# Pandas returning 0 string as 0%

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm doing a evaluation on how many stores report back in how many time (same day(0), 1 day(1), etc), but when calculate the percentage of the total, all same day stores return 0% of the total.
I tried turning the column into object, float and int, but with the same result.

```
DF['T_days'] = (DF['day included in the server'] - DF['day of sale']).dt.days
```

create my T_Days and fills it with the amount in days based on the 2 datatime columns. This works fine. And by:

```
 DF['Percentage'] = (DF['T_days'] /DF['T_days'].sum()) * 100
```

return this table. I know what i should do but now how to do it.

| COD_store | date in server | Date bought | T_days | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-03 | 2021-12-02 | 1 | 0.013746 |
| 1 | 2021-12-03 | 2021-12-02 | 1 | 0.013746 |
| 922 | 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-10 | 17 | 0.233677 |
| 922 | 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-10 | 17 | 0.233677 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 65 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-12 | 0 | 0.0 |

new DF after groupby:

```
  T_DIAS
0      0.000000
1      1.374570
2      0.192440
3     15.793814
7      0.384880
17    82.254296
Name: Percentage, dtype: float64
```

I know i should divide the days resulted by the total amount of rows in DF and then group them by days, but my search on how to do this resulted in nothing. THW: i already have a separate DF for those days and percentage

Expected table:

| T_days | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 50 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 7 |

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your original table and based on that a table containing your expected output?

Comment: If all you need is to make `0` into a `1` why not just do that before computing your percentage?

Comment: MYousefi the amount in days as 0 is nedded. As sooner a sale gets registred in the sistem, the closer each store is of the expected value for each week and month. If any sale takes too long to register, the store can be closed  to lower costs. Extreme case, but you got it.

Comment: @richardec
done.

Answer (score 0):

```
DF['T_days'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100)
```

worked. And after I turned it from a series to a DF to help the usage.